# How do I configure my VI environment on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: vimrc, linux-ubuntu

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10 and VI is exhibiting behavior I am unaccustomed to. For example, when I insert something using "i", 4 spaces are automatically placed in front of what I've inserted. Or, when I use "o", instead of creating a new line and putting me at the front of the line, it puts me 8 spaces ahead.

I'm guessing this is some kind of auto-indenting mechanism, but I don't have a .vimrc file in my home directory so not really sure where to unset this.

Comment: Does it behave like that when you start it with `vim --clean`?

Comment: Yes, it does (whether I use vi --clean or vim --clean).

Comment: You start Vim with `vim --clean` without a file name. The first thing you do is hitting `i` and Vim indents the line by 4 spaces?

Comment: My mistake.  Running vim --clean with no file name does not perform any kind of spacing/indenting when I use it.  It behaves as I expect.

Comment: Without a vimrc, its probably that defaults.vim is sourced. When editing a file where this happens, check the values of autoindent, smartindent, indentexpr, (possibly also formatoptions?). `:verbose set [opt]?` is good for this.

Comment: Do :echo $MYVIMRC , this will give you the location of .vimrc file that vim is currently using.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure what you mean by this.  I tried ':verbose set autoindent' and nothing was returned

Comment: @arunpal Same thing with ":echo $MYVIMRC".  There is no value returned.

Comment: You need the `?`—`verbose set autoindent?`

Comment: Create a .vimrc file in your home directory , and then check ":echo $MYVIMRC" in vim. If it is showing vimrc from home directory then I think auto indent will gets override.